# Adding Input Field using inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am an invoking a service using HTML and a response is retrieved.
I want to add a input field using inner HTML to the response generated in the client side.
Can you please tell me how do I do that?

Comment: JavaScript / jQuery may help you!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `innerHtml`? What you are searching is [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) or [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).